# java: generate a random point that is not inside a rectangle

Tags: java, awt, point

I have a number of rectangles, and am trying to generate a random point that is not inside any of them. I created a method to do this, but it appears that this is causing my application to freeze because it has to go through a large number of points before a valid point is generated:

```
public Point getLegalPoint() {
           Random generator = new Random();
           Point point;
           boolean okPoint = true;
           do {
                   point = new Point(generator.nextInt(975), generator.nextInt(650));
                   for (int i = 0; i < buildingViews.size(); i++) {
                           if (buildingViews.get(i).getBuilding().getRectangle()
                                           .contains(point)) {
                                   okPoint = false;
                                   break;
                           }

                   }
           } while (okPoint == false);
           return point;
   }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there a more efficient way to do it so that it won't freeze my application?

Comment: I assume that you want to generate a point INSIDE a rectangle R1 which is OUTSIDE  other rectagle R2. If this is so, you should tell us  the relative sizes of R1 R2, and if R2 is inside R1

Comment: Imagine the execution of this code if the first iteration of the for loop sets `okPoint = false`. When is it set to `true` again ?

Comment: What is the size of the rectangle? I mean, if it's very close to 975x650 then the probabilities are low and you will need a lot of iterations.

Comment: You talk about generating a point outside **a** rectangle, but the code looks like you have a collection of rectangles. That makes a big difference.

Comment: @Jesper: Actually, (s)he talks about generating a "point that is *not inside* a rectangle" (emphasis mine). This is truly ambiguous between how you read it and how it was meant to be read. (But FWIW, I read it the same way you did, and judging from other comments and answers, so did most other people!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code results to infinite loop if you don't succeed on the first try, ***okPoint = true*** must be inside the ***do*** block. See what your performance is when you fix that. 
I cannot think of a faster way as you check against multiple rectangles and not just one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:
select whether the point is  above/below/on left side/on right side of rectange (nextInt(4)) and then select random point in this area

code:

```
public Point getLegalPoint(int x, int y, int width, int height){
  Random generator = new Random();
  int position = generator.nextInt(4); //0: top; 1: right; 2: bottom; 3:right
  if (position == 0){
    return new Point(generator.nextInt(975),y-generator.nextInt(y);
  } else if (position == 2){
    return new Point(generator.nextInt(975),y+height+(generator.nextInt(650-(y+height)));
  } 
   ... same for x ...
}
```

Comment: This would not choose all points with equal probability; that may or may not matter to the OP but I'd assume that's the intent.

Comment: Ok.. that's true but the problem is only with 'corners' which has doubled probability.. it can be fixed by constraining other axis.. something like: if is selected space above than choose x from (rectangle.x, space.width), if is selected space below choose x from (0, rectangle.x+rectangle.width)

Comment: I rethinked it.. and you're right.. the probability won't be equal

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random point. Then check if it is inside bounds of rectangle. if it is then:

1. Let centerX and centerY be the x and y of the center point of rectangle.
2. if randPointX < centerX then let randPointX = randPointX - centerX
3. if randPointX > centerX then let randPointX = randPointX + centerX
4. Do same for y ordinate
5. you will need to do bounds checking again to see if the point is outside the larger view (screen i'm assuming). Just warp coordinates. so if randPointX is negative then let it equal max_X + randPointX

Comment: This doesn't generate all possible points with equal probability, and doesn't even terminate in some cases (e.g. you pick the center of the rectangle).